# Doctrine2 - Trigger event on property change (PropertyChangeListener)

Tags: php, events, doctrine-orm, eventtrigger, propertychangelistener

*I am not writing "what did I try" or "what is not working" since I can think of many ways to implement something like this. But I cannot believe that no one did something similar before and that is why I would like to ask the question to see what kind of Doctrine2 best practices show up.*

---

What I want is to trigger an event on a property change. So let's say I have an entity with an `$active` property and I want a `EntityBecameActive` event to fire for each entity when the property changes from `false` to `true`.

Other libraries often have a `PropertyChanged` event but there is no such thing available in Doctrine2.

So I have some entity like this:

```
<?php

namespace Application\Entity;

class Entity
{
    /**
     * @var int
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer");
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var boolean
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean", nullable=false)
     */
    protected $active = false;

    /**
     * Get active.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getActive()
    {
        return $this->active;
    }

    /**
     * Is active.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function isActive()
    {
        return $this->active;
    }

    /**
     * Set active.
     *
     * @param bool $active
     * @return self
     */
    public function setActive($active)
    {
        $this->active = $active;
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe [ChangeTracking](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cookbook/implementing-the-notify-changetracking-policy.html) Policy is what you want, maybe it is not!

> The NOTIFY policy is based on the assumption that the entities notify
>   interested listeners of changes to their properties. For that purpose,
>   a class that wants to use this policy needs to implement the
>   NotifyPropertyChanged interface from the Doctrine\Common namespace.

Check full example in link above.

```
class MyEntity extends DomainObject
{
    private $data;
    // ... other fields as usual

    public function setData($data) {
        if ($data != $this->data) { // check: is it actually modified?
            $this->onPropertyChanged('data', $this->data, $data);
            $this->data = $data;
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

---

This is a full example but silly one so you can work on it as you wish. It just demonstrates how you do it, so don't take it too serious!

**entity**

```
namespace Football\TeamBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="country")
 */
class Country extends DomainObject
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="smallint")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=2, unique=true)
     */
    protected $code;

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set code
     *
     * @param string $code
     * @return Country
     */
    public function setCode($code)
    {
        if ($code != $this->code) {
            $this->onPropertyChanged('code', $this->code, $code);
            $this->code = $code;
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get code
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getCode()
    {
        return $this->code;
    }
}
```

**domainobject**

```
namespace Football\TeamBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\NotifyPropertyChanged;
use Doctrine\Common\PropertyChangedListener;

abstract class DomainObject implements NotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private $listeners = array();

    public function addPropertyChangedListener(PropertyChangedListener $listener)
    {
        $this->listeners[] = $listener;
    }

    protected function onPropertyChanged($propName, $oldValue, $newValue)
    {
        $filename = '../src/Football/TeamBundle/Entity/log.txt';
        $content = file_get_contents($filename);

        if ($this->listeners) {
            foreach ($this->listeners as $listener) {
                $listener->propertyChanged($this, $propName, $oldValue, $newValue);

                file_put_contents($filename, $content . "\n" . time());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**controller**

```
namespace Football\TeamBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Football\TeamBundle\Entity\Country;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        // First run this to create or just manually punt in DB
        $this->createAction('AB');
        // Run this to update it
        $this->updateAction('AB');

        return $this->render('FootballTeamBundle:Default:index.html.twig', array('name' => 'inanzzz'));
    }

    public function createAction($code)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $country = new Country();
        $country->setCode($code);
        $em->persist($country);
        $em->flush();
    }

    public function updateAction($code)
    {
        $repo = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('FootballTeamBundle:Country');
        $country = $repo->findOneBy(array('code' => $code));
        $country->setCode('BB');

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->flush();
    }
}
```

And have this file with 777 permissions (again, this is test) to it: `src/Football/TeamBundle/Entity/log.txt`

When you run the code, your log file will have timestamp stored in it, just for demonstration purposes.

Comment: That looks indeed very interesting, I will dive in the docs :)

Comment: I used it for same reason as yours so have a look to see if it satisfies your exact needs.

Comment: Also look at http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/change-tracking-policies.html

Comment: Do you just add the listener in the constructor?

Comment: It has been very long time since I last used but I'll try to find an example.

Comment: Constructor is of course not an option since Doctrine skips calling the constructor method when instantiating entities...

Comment: @Wilt - Full example is above now.

Comment: Ah I see, you don't really connect a listener but just add your custom (boiler plate) code inside the `onPropertyChanged` method... I am not sure if this is desired since I rather keep my objects unaware of this code (that is why I want to use listeners in the first place). But thanks for the answer though. I will accept it since you answered my question correctly and connecting the listener is maybe out of the question scope.

Comment: I don't like my entities are being bloated with extra codes either so I think you're better off with an [Entity Listener](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/faep/listening-on-an-entity-with-an-entity-listener)