# Doctrine: many-to-many get removed associated object inside an event listener

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have many to many association like this

```
Entity Car
{
   /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="cars", fetch="EXTRA_LAZY")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(
     *  name="cars_users",
     *  joinColumns={
     *      @ORM\JoinColumn(name="car_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     *  },
     *  inverseJoinColumns={
     *      @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     *  }
     * )
     */
    protected $users; 

    /**
     * @param $user
      */
    public function removeUser(User $user)
    {
        if (!$this->users->contains($user)) {
            return;
        }

        $this->users->removeElement($user);
        $user->removeCar($this);

        return $this;
    }
}

Entity User 
{
/**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Car", mappedBy="users")
     */
    protected $cars;
}
```

in my controller i have

```
$carA = getRandomCar();
$userB = getAUserThatBelongToCarA();

//remove association between Car A and User B
$carA->removesUser($userB);
doctrineUpdateCar($carA);
```

I have a Doctrine Listener `CarListener` i'm trying to find out if a `User` has been removed inside that listener and tell which `User` is that.

i tried `preUpdate` `postUpdate` `postFlush` but couldn't figure out a way to get `$userB` object inside the `CarListener`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### Event

I'd suggest you use the [onflush](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#onflush) event to have the listener/subscriber listen to, as it is dispatched after the changes are computed, but before any operations towards the database have been performed. This makes it ideal as you have potential access to all changes that are about to be made, but non of them have actually been written to the database yet (so you have the option to abort).

The listener/subscriber gets passed an `OnFlushEventArgs` object, from which you have access to the [UnitOfWork](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php). The Unit of work has 5 methods to gather the changes about to be made:

- `getScheduledEntityInsertions()`
- `getScheduledEntityUpdates()`
- `getScheduledEntityDeletions()`
- `getScheduledCollectionUpdates()`
- `getScheduledCollectionDeletions()`

#### Collections

What you are doing is removing a `User` from the collection `Car::$users` and removing a `Car` from the collection `User::cars`.

So no entities are actually deleted, no fields are being changed. In stead you're changing collections. In other words, it's `getScheduledCollectionUpdates()` you want to be looking at.

The collection(s) returned by `getScheduledCollectionUpdates()` are an instance of [PersistentCollection](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/PersistentCollection.php), which has these methods to tell you what has changed:

- `getInsertDiff()`
- `getDeleteDiff()`

In your case you can use `getDeleteDiff()` to find out which entity has been removed from the collection.

Answer (score 0):

Your `preUpdate` listener will receive a `PreUpdateEventArgs` object which you can use to get a lot of information about the changes to be persisted with methods like `hasChangedField()`. More info here:

http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#preupdate

Comment: `getEntityChangeSet()` is `null` i think it's related to the `many-to-many` and associated entities

Answer (score 0):

Doctrine really behaves strangely... Had the same problem in a more complex environment. So I decided to replicate the car and user class from your example. Used exactly the same entities except the removeUser function in the car entity. Think this would be much shorter:

```
class Car
{
    public function removeUser(User $user)
    {
        $this->users->removeElement($user);
    }
}
```

In the controller I got this:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

$cars = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Car');
$users = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:User');

$car = $cars->findOneById(2);
$removeUser = $users->findOneById(3);

$car->removeUser($removeUser);
// $em->flush();
```

The user with the ID #3 is always removed from the car #2. The DELETE-statement is executed whether the entry in the car_user table exists or not.
If I comment in the flush method on the `EntityManager` ($em) the `onFlush` event is called. The functions `getScheduledEntityInsertions()`, `getScheduledEntityUpdates()`, `getScheduledEntityDeletions()`, `getScheduledCollectionDeletions()` and `getScheduledCollectionUpdates()` on the UnitsOfWork object just returning empty arrays...

I think the simplest way would be to notify yourself about the changes. Found a simple way to track them by hand over an annotation. Here are the links:

- [Doctrine: Change Tracking Policies - Notify](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/change-tracking-policies.html#notify)
- [Implementing the Notify ChangeTracking Policy](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/cookbook/implementing-the-notify-changetracking-policy.html)
- [Doctrine2 - Trigger event on property change (PropertyChangeListener)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31179323/doctrine2-trigger-event-on-property-change-propertychangelistener?answertab=active#tab-top)

Comment: @ra-htial: I will test the `ChangeTracking Policy` tomorrow by myself. But it is already late where I'm from :-)

Comment: btw regarding `removeUser` depends ... sometimes this is not enough trust me, to be on the safe side you have to make sure that you remove it from both entities.

Comment: `Jasper N. Brouwer` solved the issue perfectly check his answer